# What's the correct way to configure TcpNetClientConnectionFactory for a SSL connection when you don't need to provide a certificate?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-integration

While configuring a TCP connection using SSL, based on the spring docs we've being using our own instance of `TcpSSLContextSupport` since `DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport` requires a client certificate to be initialized. Here's our bean config:

```
private static final int SERIALIZER_HEADER_SIZE = 2;

@Bean
public ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer byteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer() {
    return new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer(SERIALIZER_HEADER_SIZE);
}

@Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory tcpClientConnectionFactory() {
    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory connFactory =
        new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(props.getUrl(), props.getPort());
    connFactory.setSerializer(byteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer());
    connFactory.setDeserializer(byteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer());
    connFactory.setSoTimeout(props.getSoTimeout());

    if (props.isUseSSL()) {
        connFactory.setTcpSocketFactorySupport(new DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport(() -> {
            return SSLContext.getDefault();
        }));
    }

    return connFactory;
}
```

Since the client certificate is a known certificate and we won't need to provide our own keystore and truststore, is this the correct way to configure SSL properly while creating a TCP connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, that is exactly the way to inject your custom `SSLContext` into the `ConnectionFactory`.

You may also consider to "trust all" in that your context:

```
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
        new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];  
                return myTrustedAnchors;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
        }
    };

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    return sc;
```

Comment: Note that client auth is off by default so you should be able to also point to empty stores. We have a [test case here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/SocketSupportTests.java#L339-L346) that specifically enables client auth.

Comment: Thank you both, the test cases are very clarifying :)